# Generating a vector of values which sum to one but the elements should be approximately but NOT exactly uniform

Tags: r, random

Suppose I want to make a vector of length N.  My goal is to ensure that all the elements are approximately 1/N (but not all elements should be exactly 1/N) and the sum of the vector should equal to one.  Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: `rep(1/N, N)`, and then you add some random variation to the vector.

Comment: But then how would I ensure that the vector sums to one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Dirichlet distribution, with large and equal parameters.

```
> library(bayesm)
> rdirichlet(c(100,100,100))
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3360327
[2,] 0.3280179
[3,] 0.3359495
> rdirichlet(c(10000,10000,10000))
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3311760
[2,] 0.3353209
[3,] 0.3335032
> rdirichlet(c(1000000,1000000,1000000))
          [,1]
[1,] 0.3330997
[2,] 0.3334884
[3,] 0.3334119
```